# No puedo acceder a POST dentro de mi clase en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario en HTML con method="POST" y un botón submit. Dentro de mi archivo 'compras.controlador.php', si hago un var_dump($_POST), se pueden ver todas mis variables POST pertenecientes a los inputs del formulario correctamente.

Ahora bien, tengo otro archivo llamado 'aux.php' al que le llega un array por AJAX y luego se lo paso a una función de una clase del archivo 'compras.controlador.php'. Allí, quiero manipular el array y las variables POST que están llegando, pero sólo me permite manipular el array, las POST dentro de la función no existen.

¿Alguno sabe qué estoy haciendo mal?

**Comparto el código de compras.controlador.php:**

```
//ACÁ ME MUESTRA LAS VARIABLES POST COMO EL 'registroUsuario', ETC.
var_dump($_POST)

    class Compras {

        public function ctrEfectivo(&$arrayCompleto){

            //ACÁ SE MUESTRA EL ARRAY CORRECTAMENTE
            var_dump("Muestro mi array dentro de la clase y función: ", $arrayCompleto);

            if(isset($_POST["registroUsuario"])){

                if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', $_POST["registroUsuario"]) &&
                   preg_match('/^([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(\/|-)(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\2(\d{4})$/', $_POST["registroCalendario"]) &&
                   preg_match('/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/', $_POST["registroEmail"]) &&
                   preg_match('/^(?:\D*\d){2,4}\D*$/', $_POST["registroDireccion"]) &&
                   preg_match('/^[0-9]{7,12}$/', $_POST["registroTelefono"])) {

                 //ACÁ QUIERO MANIPULAR TODO, PERO NO PUEDO YA QUE NO ESTÁN LLEGANDO LOS POST

    }
```

**Y acá les dejo el archivo aux.php:**

```
if(isset($_POST['arrayCompleto'])){

include ('compras.controlador.php');

$arrayCompleto = json_decode($_POST['arrayCompleto'], true);

$nuevaCompra = new Compras();
$nuevaCompra -> ctrEfectivo($arrayCompleto);

}
```

**Este es el formulario HTML:**

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return validacionForm()" id="formCash">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="registroUsuario" name="registroUsuario" placeholder="Nombre Completo" maxlength="26" required>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="registroDireccion" name="registroDireccion" placeholder="Dirección de envío con altura de calle" required>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="registroCalendario" name="registroCalendario" placeholder="Día de envío" required>

    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="registroEmail" name="registroEmail" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" maxlength="32" required>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="registroTelefono" name="registroTelefono" placeholder="Teléfono de contacto" maxlength="16" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" required>       

      <?php

      $compra = new Compras();
      $compra -> ctrEfectivo();

      ?>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-default backColor btnPagar" id="btnPagar" value="CONFIRMAR PEDIDO">

</form>
```

Comment: Porque no pasas todo el post a la funcion en lugar de solo `arrayCompleto`

Comment: @alanfcm ahora pruebo eso y te digo. Creo que debería funcionar!

Comment: ¿Validaste que efectivamente los índices que llamas existen sobre la raíz de $_POST? ¿no están sobre otro índice? ¿podrías añadir el formulario como lo tienes o parte del mismo?

Comment: @Chofoteddy Si si, lo he validado. De todos modos, ahora agrego el formulario para que lo tengas a mano.

Comment: @Chofoteddy ahí he añadido el formulario como me has pedido. Sigo intentando, pero teniendo en cuenta que las variables POST tienen que estar disponibles en todos los ámbitos, no entiendo porque no lo están en la clase y funcion que describo :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Damian ten en cuenta que estás creando una *instancia*  de la clase, por tanto, el contenido de `$_POST`, aunque sea una super global no estará disponible en la clase en sí, ni tampoco debería estarlo (como superglobal), porque hablamos de dos ámbitos distintos.

Aquí es preciso entender algo más sobre las `clases` y la Programación Orientada a Objetos: lo correcto es proveer a tu método `ctrEfectivo` todos los datos que él necesita para trabajar dentro de él. Si dicho método necesita algo más de lo que hay en `$arrayCompleto`, simplemente debes pasarle *ese algo más que él necesita* cuando invocas al método<sup>1</sup>.

Dicho de otro modo: los datos del POST se encuentran disponibles en el contexto donde creas la instancia de la clase con `new`, y si los necesitas en algún método de la clase, tienes que pasárselo desde ese ámbito.

En la práctica, sería esto:

```
class Compras {

    public function ctrEfectivo($arrData){

        //ACÁ SE MUESTRA EL ARRAY CORRECTAMENTE
        var_dump("Muestro mi array dentro de la clase y función: ", $arrData);

        if(isset($arrData["registroUsuario"])){

            if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', $arrData["registroUsuario"]) &&
               preg_match('/^([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(\/|-)(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\2(\d{4})$/', $arrData["registroCalendario"]) &&
               preg_match('/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/', $arrData["registroEmail"]) &&
               preg_match('/^(?:\D*\d){2,4}\D*$/', $arrData["registroDireccion"]) &&
               preg_match('/^[0-9]{7,12}$/', $arrData["registroTelefono"])) {

             //ACÁ QUIERO MANIPULAR TODO, PERO NO PUEDO YA QUE NO ESTÁN LLEGANDO LOS POST

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Si el método necesita **todo lo que hay en el `$_POST`**, le puedes pasar el POST completo al método:

```
  /*Aquí creas la instancia de la clase con new*/
  $compra = new Compras();
  /*Aquí le pasas todo lo que hay en el POST, porque está disponible en ESTE contexto*/
  $compra -> ctrEfectivo($_POST);
```

Ahora bien, para evitar confusiones, nótese que en la clase he llamado al parámetro `$arrData` y que todas las verificaciones que hago son en base a `$arrData`. Podrías dejar `$_POST`, pero estarías escribiendo un código muy confuso. En realidad `$arrData`  es lo mismo que `$_POST`, pero como super global POST no existe en el contexto de la clase, existe (como `$arrData`) porque se lo pasaste en parámetro al método.

O sea, las clases no son archivos cualesquiera, son envoltorios, representaciones de objetos. Cuando usas clases no es que enlaces un archivo con otro como haría con `include` o `require`, sino que trabajas con instancias de objetos a los cuales debes proveer lo necesario para que sus métodos  hagan el trabajo para el que están programados.

¿Qué ventaja tiene esto? Muchísimas. Por ejemplo, tu clase `Compras` representa una entidad completa de tu aplicación, cada vez que vayas a trabajar con compras la puedes usar. La puedes dotar de varios métodos (las diferentes funciones que se hacen con una `Compra`), puedes mapear resultados de una tabla `compras` de la base de datos, puedes hacer operaciones complicadas en diferentes partes del programa con una sola llamada a un método de la clase, la puedes relacionar con otros objetos... En definitiva, la POO es otro mundo y además escribes un código pensando en la realidad de la vida.

El código de la respuesta no es perfecto... todavía el POST debería ser verificado, que no esté vacío, etc. Y todos tus `preg_match` bueno, dan un poco de miedo verlos, quizá eso se pueda mejorar, pero no quiero liarte demasiado la cabeza. Aquí lo importante es dar un paso más en el entendimiento de cómo funcionan las clases y sus métodos y o más bien la programación orientada a objetos en sí.

---

1. Eso no quiere decir que todo haya que pasarlo en parámetro al método. A veces las clases tienen propiedades o campos inherentes a las mismas, y los métodos, en tanto que miembros de la clase, pueden hacer uso de esas propiedades sin tener que recibirlas en parámetro desde fuera.

Comment: No hay formas de agradecer el apoyo que le das a los usuarios de Stack. Miles de veces vi respuestas suyas hacia otros usuarios, en muchas de mis dudas y siempre fueron precisas. Su respuesta me ayuda mucho a entender cosas que hoy por hoy me hacen falta comprender mejor. Gracias! Me ha servido. Ya todo funciona con normalidad

Comment: @DamianRicobelli me alegro de que te haya servido la respuesta. Saludos.